# Can I use a nofollow a tag in the my header to nofollow all links to a page?

Tags: seo, links, nofollow, headers

- `<a href="http://example.com/wordpress/wishlist" rel="nofollow"></a>`
  or
- `<a href="http://example.com/wordpress/wishlist" rel="nofollow">`

I want to nofollow all the links to `http://example.com/wordpress/wishlist`. So I want to put the above code into `header.php`. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you using WordPress ?

Comment: Yes, I am using WordPress. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to nofollow all the links to `http://example.com/wordpress/wishlist`. So I want to put the above code into header.php. Is that correct?

- NO, if you're trying to put this into header if all links from your website does not have this link. (Even though you get a nofollow, you're just trying to show an irrelevant link)
- YES, If every single page of your website contains this URL from your header, yes, putting the code below in `header.php` will help you:

`<a href="http://example.com/wordpress/wishlist" rel="nofollow"></a>`

or

`<a href="http://example.com/wordpress/wishlist" rel="nofollow">`